# How to click on android soft key buttons using appium-jvm

Tags: jvm, appium

Any help would be appreciated.

I need to click or tap on Go/Done button on android s3 device which running 4.3 version

I tried all sorts of option

1. driver.pressKeyEvent(66) or
   driver.pressKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER)
2. Driver.sendKeyEvent(66)
3. driver.execute("mobile:keyevent", "keycode:66");

I manage to click on all keys except enter button
Enviroments

```
Appium version - 1.4.13
Java 1.7
appium depen- 3.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

Comment: I tried driver.tap(1,703,1273,1) -> Its working on one device but , for sure it will fail if i change my device

Comment: what's the error u get while trying above? it works for me no issues at all. try to upgrade your java client and try again.

Comment: error msg: The method sendKeyEvent(int) is undefined  for the type AndroidDriver

Comment: Which appium dependency are you using? mine is 3.2.0 latest version

Comment: change your appium driver to driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("port"));